# How to prevent internal structs from being visible to the user of the API?

Tags: c, api, api-design

### api.h

The following API is assumed to be distributed as a shared library.

```
#include "apiInternal.h"

internalStruct* API_init();
extern void API_set_member1(internalStruct* apiStruct, int value);
extern void API_set_member2(internalStruct* apiStruct, int value);
```

### apiInternal.h

```
typedef struct internalStruct {
    int member1;
    int member2;
} internalStruct;
```

### sample.c

The program `sample.c` uses `api.h` and links with the shared library to use the API.
    #include "api.h"

```
int main()
{
    internalStruct *myVar = API_init();
    API_set_member1(myVar, 5);
    API_set_member2(myVar, 6);
}
```

The dilemma here is,

1. Should the `api.h` that the API implementation uses be different than
   the `api.h` distributed to the users of the API? If so, how can I do
   this without including `apiInternal.h`?
2. Is there a better way to do/design this?

Comment: What if the struct you make public has only one member of type void*, that you internally cast into the actual(private) struct when you manipulate it inside your public functions?

Comment: What is the user of the API supposed to do with the struct pointer anyway?  Do you want them to treat it as an opaque handle which they never de-reference, but only obtain and later pass back?

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yes, thats right.

Comment: Then you can either explicitly tell them it is a void * and cast it internally, or use a typedef which resolves to void * for the client, and to a struct pointer for you.  Of course this is convenience/cleanliness level abstraction - they can actually read all the memory of their process if they care to guess/discern what is there.

Comment: @ChrisStratton My objective is not to prevent users from reading data, but to dissuade them from using the struct members directly, but instead use only the API functions to manipulate them. Yes, the second option makes sense, that would mean I would have to distribute a different api.h for the API users i.e. one containing the void* typedef and one without - is there a clean way of doing this - i.e. change in the API header automatically reflects in the public header?

Comment: A (relatively cheesy) way that comes to mind is to do an #ifndef in the public header to typdef it as as `void *`, while in the internal source files you can include a private header *first*.  Anyone who goofs with the includes or accidentally doing what they shouldn't will get a nice null pointer de-reference error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build `sample.c` without including `apiInternal.h` and the structure definition.

Within `api.h` drop the `#include "apiInternal.h"`.  Instead, declare the structure, this is  called a forward declaration, (easiest to drop the typdef) so `api.h` will look like:

```
struct internalStruct;

struct internalStruct* API_init();
extern void API_set_member1(struct internalStruct* apiStruct, int value);
extern void API_set_member2(struct internalStruct* apiStruct, int value);
```

This works because the compiler can build `sample.c` as it only needs to know the size of the pointer rather than the complete structure declaration.  You then only need to include `apiInternal.h` within your library code.  You won't need to distribute `apiInternal.h` to your users.

If you library code has multiple files, then you will need `apiInternalh.h`.  Each of you library source files will include `apiInternal.h`.  If you library code is a single file, then I typically just define the structure at the top of the library C file, the extra header is not necessary.

This is called an `opaque pointer`.  The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer#C) provides an additional example.  This is nice way of achieving information-hiding from within C.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfect. Additionally its easier for me to do a `typedef struct internalStruct internalStruct' in api.h